# How to speed up mysql queries using like opertor on large text?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `products` (name varchar2(200)) which contains 7000 records and `description` (fulldescription text) which contains 10 million records. I want to search each name from `products` table in each and every row of fulldescription column .

My query:

```
select 
    name, fulldescription 
from 
    products
inner join 
    description on fulldescription like concat('%',name,'%');
```

I want the result quickly. I have indexed the full description using full text still it takes lot of time.

Is there any better way to speed up my query?

Comment: like wildcard with `%yourtext%` never uses the index.

Answer (score 0):

Full text index the best way. But change a bit your structure. Create a new table

```
create table new_table(product_id int, description_id int);
```

When insert a new product  use like this sql command;

```
INSERT INTO new_table(product_id, description_id) SELECT p_id, description_id FROM description WHERE MATCH (fulldescription) AGAINST (Product_name_string);
```

in this sql full text helps you find corresponding description ids

Comment: NB: Fulltext is only available on MyIsam tables until 5.6, when Innodb introduced it. ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-restrictions.html

Comment: Hi Ramin thanks for answering,from where did you get Product_name_String

Comment: After insert products table  INSERT INTO new_table(product_id, description_id) SELECT p_id, description_id FROM description WHERE MATCH (fulldescription) AGAINST (select name from products where id = LAST_INSERT_ID());